# KDE Neon ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 4, black screen with cursor on resume from suspend on battery

Tags: kde, suspend, thinkpad, battery, kde-neon

I am running KDE Neon on my ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 4. Whenever I resume from sleep/suspend, UNLESS it is plugged in on AC, it only resumes to a black screen with a cursor, and nothing else. I have absolutely no idea what is causing this problem. <s>I did add a script, based on another post I found with a similar problem, that disables openGL on suspend and enables it on reload. However, I have no idea if this script is for some reason not being activated on battery, or if it just doesn't do anything and it has always been like this. I am leaning towards them not doing anything, but I will test and comment. Please help!</s> I disabled this scripts, and it STILL worked fine on AC, and failed to work on battery.